# Why does a template argument of type T& resolves to T?

Tags: c++

Here for example, `b` is of type `int&` but `f(b)` resolves to `f(int)`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void f(T arg) {
    static_assert(std::is_reference<T>::value);   // fails
}

void g() {
  int a = 5;
  int& b = a;
  f(b);
}
```

I know the standard dictates it - I'm asking, why?  What goes wrong (or - becomes 'surprising') if the reference *isn't* dropped?

Comment: This is just a language design choice. The way it is makes sense, because a function template is supposed to be a _template_ for stamping out specialized versions of the function. If `void f(int arg)` is the way we write a function that can be passed an `int&` but will copy the `int&`, it makes sense for it to be the same when you generalize that function into a function template.

Comment: @Justin I don't want to copy the argument. Doesn't make sense to me that the template type deduction rules decide for me that I do.  To clarify: I know how to work around this, I'm asking about the design rationale.

Comment: A reference is an alias.  All it is, is another name for something that already exits.  That means in `f(b)`, `b` can be replaced with `a`.  What is the type of `a`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yet in C++ `int` and `int&` are distinct types, and choosing one over the other in a template instantiation has consequences (copy).

Comment: @OfekShilon: "*I don't want to copy the argument.*" But the function *does* want you to copy the object. By not specifying the template parameters explicitly, you have chosen to defer this to the function in question.

Comment: C++ value type system is dark and really-really-really obscure. Just accept it. If you want to use references, make your function argument a reference.

Comment: @SergeyA: It's not obscure; it reads like the non-template version, so it should *act* like it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah, although forwarding reference looks like an rvalue reference, but it doesn't act like it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things at play here.

What if you, as the author of `f`, *wants* to write a template function where the user is required to copy/move a parameter into the function?

In non-template code, that prototype would look like this: `void f(SomeType st);`. Any caller of `f` has no choice but to copy/move into the parameter. Whether they have an object, a reference to an object, or something else. `st` shall be an object separate and distinct from the rest.

Template argument deduction is *intended* to look like the non-template version where possible. So if you have `template<typename T> void f(T t);`, and you call it with `f(some_object)`, that *should* work exactly like the untemplated version.

The other thing at play here is that reference variables are *supposed* to just be a different name for some object. That is, `a` and `b`, should, all things being equal, behave *identically*. So `f(a)` ought to do the same thing as `f(b)`.

The rules of template argument deduction favor both of these. It keeps references behaving exactly like the object, and it allows the template function to behave like an equivalently-defined non-template version.

If you want a reference type, you must forgo template argument deduction and specify it directly: `f<decltype((b))>(b)`. Note the use of double-parentheses here; that's important for getting `decltype` to be a reference.

Comment: Thank you! One quibble: are double parantheses really necessary? This prints `11` :  `std::cout << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value << std::is_reference<decltype((b))>::value;`

Answer (score 2):

According to the rules of the language, `f(b)` is not calling `f` with an expression of type `int&`. It is calling `f` with an *lvalue of type `int`*. The same would also occur if you did `f(a)`.

In general, when a reference variable is mentioned by name, it is an expression that is an lvalue of the referenced type. The fact that the variable itself is a reference is not visible to the type system.

Thus, `f` never deduces `T` to have reference type. From `f`'s point of view, the argument is never actually a reference.

Comment: Thank you, but not sure I follow yet: seems the info on `b` being a reference *isn't* lost, and seems visible to the type system. Eg:  `cout << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value;` would print `1`.  Was there some explicit decision to ignore the reference part of the type in template type deduction?

Comment: @OfekShilon When a reference variable is the operand of `decltype`, directly and without any extra parentheses, then you can observe the fact that it's a reference. You can also do it with `decltype(auto)`. Otherwise, you cannot. The `decltype` case is the one exception to the general rule.

Comment: I think single/double parentheses don't make a difference here. This prints `11` :  `std::cout << std::is_reference<decltype(b)>::value << std::is_reference<decltype((b))>::value;`

Comment: @OfekShilon It makes a difference in the case of a non-reference variable. `decltype(a)` is `int`, while `decltype((a))` is `int&`. Thus, using single parentheses, you can test for referenceness. Once you go to double parentheses, you are querying the properties of the *expression*, and the difference between reference and non-reference variables is erased.

Answer (score 1):

> What goes wrong (or - becomes 'surprising') if the reference isn't dropped?

Consider following function:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T arg) {
    something = std::move(arg);

// ...
f(lvalue);            // copies    
f(str::move(lvalue)); // moves
```

The intention is to copy from an lvalue, and move from an rvalue.

If `T` deduced to a reference, then `lvalue` argument would be moved from, which is in this case undesirable.

---

> I don't want to copy the argument.

- If you're writing the function, then specify a reference parameter using & symbol, and not an object parameter. That way the argument can never be copied into the call (you can still copy inside the function).
- If you're calling a function that accepts an object parameter, then pass an rvalue and not an lvalue. That way you will copy only if the move is a copy, and there is no copy elision involved.

> Doesn't make sense to me that the template type deduction rules decide for me that I do

**You** decided to use `T`. You should instead decide to use `T&`, `T&&` or `const T&` if you want a reference.